# Spinner height doesnot change

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have declared a spinner in my layout file. I have set a custom ArrayAdapter for this. My problem is the spinner height gets unexpectedly larger than defined when the view is rendered.

For example if I declare the spinner like this:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/categorySpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rewardListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/customerRewardPointsTextView"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Then its rendered like this:

[image]

On the other hand if I declare the spinner like this:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/categorySpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rewardListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/customerRewardPointsTextView"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Then its rendered like this:

[image]

So the problem is whether I set the `android:layout_height="45dip"` or `android:layout_height="0dip"` the height of the spinner remains the same. How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: try to adjust the height of your layout

Comment: Can you paste the entire xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are defining android:layout_height but it's not actually working because of the restriction you have in your view :

```
    android:layout_above="@+id/rewardListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customerRewardPointsTextView"
```

As you can see you placed the view between your two view "rewardListView" and "customerRewardPointsTextView". And those view actually adjusting the height of your "categorySpinner" view, so it doesn't matter whether you give 45dip or 0dip.

Try placing  "categorySpinner" in your relatvielayout in a way so other view does not mess up with categorySpinner's height.